# Type-safe Client-Server API with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Let's consider example, the implementation of `getUser`, the usage on the client would be like that

```
const user = await getUser(http, { id: '1' })
```

The working but not very type-safe implementation

```
// ./api.ts - shared interfaces
const endpoint = '/users'
interface Arg { id: string }
interface Resp { name: string }

// ./client-api.ts - client side
import { endpoint, Arg, Resp } from './api.ts'
function getUser(http: HttpClient, arg: Arg): Promise<Resp> {
  return http.get(endpoint, arg)
}

// ./server-api.ts - server side
import { endpoint, Arg, Resp } from './api.ts'
function getUser(db: Db, arg: Arg): Promise<Resp> {
  return db.findById(arg.id)
}
// Additionally it needs to be registered
httpServer.on(endpoint, (params) => getUser(db, params))
```

Problems: too many boilerplate, it's possible to mismatch `Arg` from one method with `Resp` from another, or mismatch `endpoint`, or forget to register endpoint on the server.

Possible **better implementation** could be like code below. Although it also doesn't enforce endpoint and it's possible to forget to register server side handler:

```
// ./api.ts
interface GetUser {
  endpoint: '/users',
  arg:      { id: string },
  resp:     { name: string }
}

type ClientFn<Command> = no idea how to do that, some TS magic
type ServerFn<Command> = no idea how to do that, some TS magic

// ./client-api.ts
const getUser: ClientFn<GetUser> = (http, arg) => http.get(endpoint, arg)

// ./server-api.ts
const getUser: ServerFn<GetUser> = (db, arg) => db.findById(arg.id)
httpServer.on(endpoint, (params) => getUser(db, params))
```

Do you know a **better way** to do that? Or **maybe some code-generation lib** in TypeScript that can do that?

Comment: Your idea is generally sound. The only issue is that you don't have to bundle the endpoints, arg, and resp in an interface (that's the problem you have). You can create a general mechanism that takes in those to create an `Endpoint` of `getUser`.  You can check out https://github.com/unional/fsa-emitter as an example.

Comment: i.e., `const getUser = createClientEndpoint<Arg, Resp>(endpoint, (http:, arg) => ... ))`